# Error when deploying Xamarin.Forms iOS App with XAML Hot Restart

Tags: xamarin.forms, hot-reload

I am trying to use Xamarin.Forms with Hot Restart to develop an iOS App, but I keep get the following error when running the app from Visual Studio:

*An error occurred while trying to deploy the app 'TestApp2.iOS.app'. Details: Error running hotrestart: 'An error occurred while deploying the application 'TestApp2.iOS.app' into 'iPhone'. Details: Could not write content to file 'PublicStaging/com.companyname.TestApp2'. ErrorCode: EmptyResponse'. Command: 'deploy -u=00000XXX-001D4C6XXXXXXXXX -i=com.companyname.TestApp2 -n=TestApp2.iOS.app'*

Details:

- Visual Studio v16.8.2 (and v16.9.0 Preview 1.0) on Windows 10
- Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.1687
- Xamarin.Essentials v1.5.3.2
- I used "Create new project" in VS, with the template "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)" (Only iOS, no Android). I've not done any manual changes to the project after it was created.
- I have enabled Hot Restart via Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features -> Enable Xamarin Hot Restart
- The phone is connected to the PC via USB cable and I can see the name of my phone appear on the "Play Button" in Visual studio.
- I do not see any activity on my phone and nothing in the VS device log that seems related.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> The phone is connected to the PC via USB cable and I can see the name of my phone appear on the "Play Button" in Visual studio.

You need a Mac and **[Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/)**. Then we will see the following screenshot:

[image]

Now you can select one device from the device list to run.

[image]

================================update================================

**First**, enable hot restart in visual stuido 2019(here version is `16.8.2`). Not forgert to restart the visual studio after enabling it.

[image]

**Second**, make sure the iTunes has logined a **paid apple account** and connect a physical device via usb.

[image]

**Third**, set iOS as the startup project, then you will see your physical device:

[image]

**Last**, setting provisioning file in **ios Bndele Signing**:

[image]

**Now** you can run it in your physical device.

Comment: I thought with the new Hot Reload functionality you didn't need a Mac in order to run a development build on a device?

Comment: @Bijington No, you also need a Mac to run the program.

Comment: I realized I was mixing together Hot Reload and Hot Restart. It was my impression after reading about Hot Restart that you could do that from a Windows PC. 

For example here: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/
I also watched this video on channel9: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Hot-Restart-Easily-Debug-to-iOS-Devices

Would it be correct to say that I still need to do the initial deploy to the phone from a Mac and then I can use a Windows PC to deploy changes to the app using Hot Restart?

Comment: @Quix Hi, you are using a preview version of visual stuido 2019?

Comment: I've tried both the latest stable version (v16.8.2) and 16.9.0 Preview 1.0

Comment: @Quix Hi, I have tried in my visual studio (`16.8.2`), and it works. Whether you use a paid apple account and select the matching provisioning file.

Comment: @Quix I have updated the asnwer, you could have a look at that when you have time.

Comment: Thank you for the effort but I am afraid I still get the same error. I have tried restart of everything and to recreate the project. Everything works fine until I get the deploy error

Comment: @Quix What device are you testing? You could have a check witht the limitations whether contains some points.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations

Comment: That is false u do not  need  a mac paired for hot reload hot reload should  work with just a developer account thats the whole point and a iphone

Answer (score 0):

try to clear trusted computers on your iPhone, under Settings->Developer->Paired Devices, then reconnect the phone. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a mac to debug on physical device any more.
There are some limitations but it works.
Here are the best set up instructions I found so far:
https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/

After following these instructions I was getting similar error.
In my case it was ReSharper build runner that I had to disable and it all worked.