# Cannot deploy Xamarin.Forms app to physical iPad [PublicStaging]

Tags: xamarin, ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am able to deploy to the simulator without issue. When I try to deploy to a physical iPad, I get this error:

```
Writing content to file 'PublicStaging/com.productname'...
Xamarin.iOS.Windows.HotRestartClient Error: 0 : 
Deploy Error: Could not write content to file 'PublicStaging/com.productname'
2>Deploy failed. The app 'ProductName.iOS.app' could not be deployed to the device 'Development iPad'. Please check the logs for more details.
```

Thus far, I have found no logs with any information of any value. Because this product is intermingled with another product, which is not built for the simulator and outside of my development organization, I am unable to simply deploy both to the simulator.

I have followed the steps in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079433/error-when-deploying-xamarin-forms-ios-app-with-xaml-hot-restart/65083934#65083934) without success. I am currently running Visual Studio 17.3.2.

Comment: In addition, if I try to deploy (using the Deploy menu item) without debugging, I get this error in 2022:
Deploy Error: An Lockdown error occurred. The error code was MuxError
1>Deploy failed. The app 'ProductName.iOS.app' could not be deployed to the device 'Development iPad'. Error: An error occurred on client IDBLocal while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/deploy-app. Please check the logs for more details.

Comment: And in 2019:
2>Deploy failed. The app 'ProductName.iOS.app' could not be deployed to the device 'Development iPad'. Error: The post for client vs25844scott on topic xvs/idb/deploy-app has been cancelled. Please check the logs for more details.

Comment: I've never seen a mention of a `PublicStaging` folder before. I would DISABLE HotRestart - but that probably won't make any difference. Did you use Xcode / Devices and Simulators / Devices to look for a log? It might be something about the relationship between your app and the other app. As a test, can you temporarily remove any such dependency, see if you can deploy the app on its own?

Comment: Connecting the iPad to the Mac and turning off HotRestart did the trick. Not sure why, but whatever. I don't know why I hadn't considered that solution. Likely because I'm annoyed and not thinking straight at this point. If you move this to an answer, I'll mark it.